# Dynamic object using group values as keys

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm developing a Asp.Net WebAPI with EntityFramework, and need to return some definitions using dynamic values as keys. Definitions are stored in a definition table as follows:

```
 NICK     VALUE   DESCRIPTION
------    -----  --------------
GRADE      1      Very low
GRADE      2      Low
GRADE      3      Fair
GRADE      4      High
GRADE      5      Very high
CONTROL    1      There is no control
CONTROL    2      Control is fairly structured
...        ...    ...
```

Instead of getting the definition's list as usual:

```
[ { "nick": "GRADE", "value": 1, "description": "Very low" },
  { "nick": "GRADE", "value": 2, "description": "Low" }, ... 
]
```

I'd like to get the structure below:

```
[ "GRADE": [ 
    { "value": 1, "description": "Very low" }, 
    {"value": 1, "description": "Low" } ...
    ],
  "CONTROL": [ ... ]
]
```

using a WebAPi function like:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<ValueDescription>> GetDefinitions()
```

where ValueDescription is a simple class as follows:

```
public class ValueDescription {
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I tried many approaches, but I can't figure out how to get the structure with dynamic key names. Anyone can give me a clue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the definitions by `NICK` and then use [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) method passing the group `Key` as dictionary key and projecting group elements to `ValueDescription` list as dictionary value.

Something like this:

```
var result = db.Definitions
    .GroupBy(e => e.NICK)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(e => new ValueDescription
    {
        Value = e.VALUE,
        Description = e.DESCRIPTION,
    }).ToList());
```